# missing Cuda 12.1 driver for Linux aarch64

Tags: cuda

after installing Cuda12.1 on Jetson Xavier NX (Linux, Ubuntu 20.04, aarch64)  I can’t find the CUDA 12.1 driver for Linux aarch64… (I do find an old driver for 11.4) Could you please help identify, locate and download.

Appreciate the help!

Note: my little test program outputs:

**cudaGetDeviceProperties** failed: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
**CUDA Driver Version**: 11.4
**CUDA Runtime Version**: 12.1
**CUDA Device Name**:
**CUDA Compute Capability**: -1785077984.65535
**CUDA Device Memory**: 281473195962368 bytes
**cudaMalloc failed**: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

**nvcc --version** returns:
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Apr__3_17:19:26_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.105
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32688072_0

(Cuda 12.1 update release notes table 1 indicate Cuda compatibility with aarch64-Jetson, I installed Cuda 12.1Toolkit )

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-for-tegra-appnote/index.html#use-the-right-upgrade-package

Answer (score 1):

Solved by Nvidia moderator:

The GPU driver for Jetson is integrated into the OS and the latest version is 11.4.

But we support CUDA compatibility from CUDA 12.
So CUDA 12 can work with the older GPU driver version.

Have you linked the compat folder which allows users to run on an older GPU driver?

$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.0/compat